# Set value to 90th percentile for each column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, percentile

I am working with the data which looks like a DataFrame described by

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 'BBB': [2,1,3,4,6,1,2,3]})
```

What I would like to do is to set value to roundup (90%) if value exceeds the 90th percentile. So it's like capping the maximum to the 90th percentile.

This is getting trickier for me as every column is going to have different percentile value.

I am able to get 90th percentile value using:

```
df.describe(percentiles=[.9])
```

So for column BBB, 6 is greater than 4.60 (90th percentile), hence it needs to be changed to 5 (roundup 4.60).

In my actual problem I am doing this for a large matrix, so I would like to know if there is any simple solution to this, rather than creating an array of 90th percentile of columns first and then checking elements in for a column and setting those to roundup to the 90th percentile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One vectorised method would be to combine [`np.minimum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and [`df.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html):

```
>>> np.minimum(df, df.quantile(0.9))
   AAA  BBB
0    1  2.0
1    1  1.0
2    1  3.0
3    2  4.0
4    2  4.6
5    2  1.0
6    3  2.0
7    3  3.0
```

For a bigger speed boost use:

```
np.minimum(df, np.percentile(df, 90, axis=0))
```

`df.quantile` appears to be slower than `np.percentile` (possibly because it returns a Series rather than a plain NumPy array).

Comment: Not sure why, but you would notice that in the benchmarks posted, this method seems slower than apply method. +1 for cleaner single-liner.

Comment: It seems that `np.percentile` is quite a bit faster (as much as 3x) than `df.quantile` - possibly because the latter returns a Series.

Comment: just for shorter version, accepted this as answer, otherwise for me both works,..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this apply `clip_upper()` on 90 percentile value `np.percentile(x, 90)` for each column

```
In [242]: df.apply(lambda x: x.clip_upper(np.percentile(x, 90)))
Out[242]:
   AAA  BBB
0    1  2.0
1    1  1.0
2    1  3.0
3    2  4.0
4    2  4.6
5    2  1.0
6    3  2.0
7    3  3.0
```

---

I had imagined @ajcr elegant solution would faster than `apply`. **But,**

Below benchmarks for `len(df) ~ 130K`

```
In [245]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.clip_upper(np.percentile(x, 90)))
100 loops, best of 3: 7.49 ms per loop

In [246]: %timeit np.minimum(df, df.quantile(0.9))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
```

And for `len(df) ~ 1M`

```
In [248]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.clip_upper(np.percentile(x, 90)))
10 loops, best of 3: 54.5 ms per loop

In [249]: %timeit np.minimum(df, df.quantile(0.9))
10 loops, best of 3: 73.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the timings! I had thought the same thing but, having just checked timings on my machine, it appears `apply` can be surprising sometimes :-)

Comment: (Actually, it looks like `np.percentile` is the reason for the greater speed...)